# How different are SQL dialects for basic queries?

Tags: sql

New to SQL, so please excuse imprecision in the question.

For "normal" queries, is SQL syntax mutually intelligible between dialects? To take a concrete example, would `SELECT * FROM [Pending Scans]` be valid in all common dialects?

Not looking for an exhaustive list!

Comment: Your query will only work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This would be:

```
select *
from pending_scans;
```

Square braces are non-standard for escaping identifiers.  The standard escape character for identifiers is the double quote, and most databases now support that.

I should note that for all but the simplest queries -- such as the one you have written -- slight differences between dialects make it a fool's errand to try to write complete portable code.  For instance, function names are different, such as `len()` versus `length()`, and date/time operations are quite bespoke.

If you are writing an application that needs to support multiple different database types, a typical method would be to define the API as a set of views and use the views with simple `SELECT` queries (as in your example).

Comment: Thanks...so `select * pending_scans` would be a "portable" way to write that query for multiple databases?

Comment: @AlainD . . . Assuming the table name does not have a space in it.

Comment: Well, the table name is `Pending Scans` (ie. there is a space in it). Would every SQL dialect correctly understand `SELECT * FROM pending_scans`? Or would `SELECT * FROM "Pending Scans"` be preferable?

Comment: @AlainD . . . No.  You should rename the table with a standard name.  Absent that, your best best are double quotes, not square braces.